# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and IIS ORA-12154

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I'm using
- ASP.NET, C#, .NET 4.5.2
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
- Oracle.DataAccess
- Server running Windows Server 2008 SP2.

My website uses Oracle.DataAccess in most parts (e.g. login, search data). I'm migrating some parts to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (e.g. insert Permit data). The website work perfectly in both my computer and server. However, when it works about 3-4 days it will show error ORA-12154 from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess parts but Oracle.DataAccess parts still work correctly. I can login or search data but I can't insert Permit data.

My current solution is recycling Application Pool every 3-4 days and it will work again. Please suggest me. Thank you.

Here is some of exception.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
    at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution..ctor(String TNSAlias, String instanceName)
    at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
    at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName)
    at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, CriteriaCtx criteriaCtx, String instanceName)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, CriteriaCtx criteriaCtx, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, CriteriaCtx criteriaCtx, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, CriteriaCtx criteriaCtx)
    at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without some code. `ORA-12154` means the connect identifier cannot be resolved ( as the exception also states). Are you sure this is not a configuration/networking issue?

Comment: That error means your connect alias cannot be found. Where are you putting the connection alias used with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess? Investigate why that entry might become periodically unavailable. Note Oracle.DataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess can use different means of finding the alias, which is why one may work and the other may not. Investigate use of TNS_ADMIN environment/config file entries pointing to the TNSNAMES.ORA file, as well as connection aliases placed inside of app.config, web.config, and machine.config.

Comment: @Hintham Thanks for your reply. I am not sure but if it is a configuration error, it should not work since the start. If it is a network problem Oracle.DataAccess should not be work too.

Comment: @ChristianShayThanks for your reply. I set TNS_NAME to point to tnsname.ora as same as the file Oracle.DataAccess using.

Comment: The parameter is TNS_ADMIN (note that Managed ODP.NET gets the parameter from config files NOT the environment, where unmanaged can read the environment). And you need to look at situations that might arise that might make the TNS_ADMIN value be unable to be read, or the TNSNAMES.ORA temporarily unavailable. Also, you should check that it really using the TNS_ADMIN in the first place and not accidentally picking up the alias elsewhere. To sanity check, you can try making a second copy of TNSNAMES.ORA just for managed ODP.NET and also change the name of the alias so it is unique to managed.